# How to fix rxjs catchError return type for http call in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Inside my service I have a post method in which return type is IInfluencerRewardSetup

```
influencerRewardSetup(payload: IInfluencerRewardSetup): Observable<IInfluencerRewardSetup> {
    return this.httpClient.post<IInfluencerRewardSetup>(this.baseUrl, payload)
      .pipe(retry(1),
      this.errorHandler());
  }
```

and

```
private errorHandler() {
    return catchError(err => {
      this.notificationService.error(err.message, '');
      throw new Error(err.message || 'Server error');
    });
  }
```

But the problem is I am having this type of error:

```
Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<IInfluencerRewardSetup>'
```

Please note that, errorHandler will handle other HTTP calls as well.
Why am I having this error and how can I fix that type of issue here? can someone please help?